# Onclick reset setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function timer(x) {
    if (x == 1) {
        //reset timer 
        }
    var i = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {

        var x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;
        i = i + 1;

    }, 500);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>


<p id="demo">hello</p>

<button type="button" onclick="timer(0)">change</button>

<button type="button" onclick="timer(1)">reset</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to reset timer onclick . e.g. if setIntervaltime is set to 5 sec and 3 seconds are elapsed ,after that if some on click on reset button it should start gain from 5 seconds.How to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Keep the return value of `setTimeout` somewhere that you can get it again (currently you are storing it in a local variable, so it goes away when the function ends)
2. Call `clearTimeout(timer);`
3. Call `setTimeout` with whatever arguments you want again.

Comment: You can't use the same variable name to store the return value from `setTimeout` and for the `timer` function.

Comment: You can't call the `timer` function from an `onclick` attribute when you have scoped it to a function that gets called `onload`.

Comment: can you do it in fiddle i am very new to all this?

Answer (score 3):

As already Quentin mentioned, use `clearInterval` to solve your problem.

Wrap it within an `if.else..` statement like

```
if(x == 1) {
   clearTimeout(timeout);
}
else {
    timeout = setInterval.....  // otherwise even after resetting
                                // it will continue to increment the value
}
```

**Complete Code:**

```
var timeout;  // has to be a global variable
function timer(x) {
    var i = 0;
    if (x == 1) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;
    } else {
        timeout = setInterval(function () {
            var x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;
            i = i + 1;
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hxEy/4/)